# Race Condition in Spring WebFlux

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux

I have a class that declares HmacUtils as following:

`public static final HmacUtils HMAC_UTILS = new HmacUtils(HmacAlgorithms.HMAC_MD5, "secret");`

And then one of the methods of my class uses the `HMAC_UTILS.hmacHex` method.

I have identified a flaky test that relates to this. For the same inputs to `hmacHex` the assertions fail because sometimes the value returned from the method differs from the expectation.
This caused me to think about race conditions. Making the method that calls `hmacHex` **synchronized** solved the issue, meaning that there are no more flaky tests.

How can it be that some underlying netty threads ended up in a race condition? From my understanding I should not be worried about race conditions with spring webflux since I'm not managing/creating threads myself.

I expect that working with spring webflux when I'm not directly managing threads should not make my think about thread-safety.

Comment: Thread safety is not only about avoiding race conditions. You have multiple threads (no matter by who created) that calls same class. That class have some fields and multiple threads write and read them in parallel. If the class is nit synchronized in some way, it easily could end up in one thread reading fields written by another one

Comment: I see, its not tied to spring webflux or web for instance, but rather how we set mutable state that is available  for changes in the heap

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the [`HmacUtils`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/digest/HmacUtils.html) from the Apache Commons Codec project, the documentation states the following (emphasis is mine).

> This class is immutable and thread-safe. **However the Mac may not be.**

So the `HmacUtils` itself is thread-safe, going by this message this can only mean that the `Mac` you are using isn't. By default it will use the ones from the Crypto library from the JDK. And I believe that the MD5 digest in there is, indeed, not thread-safe.

**NOTE:** I had a quick look and the MD5 from the standard library is keeping state, which is modified/worked on in the MD5. So multiple threads shouldn't share a single MD5 instance I think.

You might try to use the MD5 from the Bouncy Castle library which might be thread-safe.